# Как запускать скрипт при переходе с другой страницы на другую?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Перед переходом на другую страницу ты должен выбрать необходимые пункты option и нажать кнопку "Найти".
После нажатия кнопки открывается другая страница с фильтром. В фильтр вставляются значения select с предыдущей страницы с помощью localstorage. Но чтобы фильтр сработал нужно нажать кнопку "Подобрать" уже на странице фильтра

Главная страница:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Основной фильтр при нажатии на кнопку "Найти":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрипт, по которому фильтруются программы:

```js
function applyFilters() {
    // Инициализация классов
    var direction1 = $("#direction1").val();
    var level1 = $("#level1").val();
    var universities = $("#universities").val();
    var language = $("#language").val();
    var program = $("#program").val();
    // Создания селектора
    var selector = "#card-wrapper-first ." + direction1 + "." + level1 + "." + program + "." + language + "." + universities;

    // Появление нового запроса
    $('#card-wrapper-first .card-item').hide();
    $(selector).show();
}
```

**Мне нужно сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопку "Найти" меня перебрасывало на другую страницу (отображение всех программ, подходящих по фильтру) и выполнялся скрипт по выбранным настройкам (Уровень подготовки, направление образования)**

*Сейчас скрипт поиска(выше) выполняется только по нажатию кнопки "Подобрать"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте привязать обработчик события `load` с вызовом нужной функции к `body`:

```
<body onload=applyFilters()>
...
</body>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, как-то не додумался)